# How to call a function from a variable, when the variable calls the function and the function includes the variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This is kind of paradoxic, but I can't find a solution. My problem actually started out as a Tkinter button that destroys itself: `Button=Tk.button(root, text="Press me!", command=Button.destroy())`

But I get the error `NameError: name 'Button' is not defined` so I guess I can't use that. I then tried:

```
import tkinter as Tk

root=Tk.Tk()

def DeleteButton():

    Button.destroy()

Button=Tk.button(root, text="Press me!", command=DeleteButton())

root.mainloop()
```

`DeleteButton()` contains the variable Button, so I have to put the declaration of Button before the function. But Button calls the function, so the function has to come first. Note I only have a few months experience using Python so I'm not great.

Comment: It should be `command=DeleteButton`, without parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda to create an anonymous function.

```
Button = Tk.button(root, text="Press me!", command = lambda:Button.destroy())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as Tk

root=Tk.Tk()

def DeleteButton():
    Button.destroy()

Button=Tk.Button(root, text="Press me!", command=DeleteButton)
Button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what you did and why.

Comment: Sure, i will follow the guidelines.

Comment: @Xythprynx: You should edit your answer to provide the explanation Barmar has requested.